# How to find segment indices of vector in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing

Suppose I have a vector which contains `person_ids` like this :

```
x = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4]
```

so the first 3 items are for person 1. How can I find the vector indices that a new person starts?

i.e. my function should return

```
f(x) = [1,4,6,10];
```

is there a MATLAB way for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the person IDs are sorted, and the IDs cannot be negative, you can do this using

```
>> x = [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4];
>> find(diff([-1 x]))
ans =

    1    4    6   10
```

Comment: Your assumptions are correct for my case, so this solves my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Praetorian's answer is quite nice, but if you want another alternative, you can use the second output of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html).  The second output determines the locations of the first **unique** value for a particular input sequence.

Also assuming that the person IDs are sorted, you can simply do this:

```
[~,y,~] = unique(x)

y =

 1
 4
 6
10
```

---

## Minor Note

If you look at the [`unique` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), before version R2013a, it used to find the location **the last** unique value for an input sequence in your array.  This has now changed to the first location as of R2013a... which is the version I have.  As such, should you have a version of MATLAB that is before R2013a, you need to add the `'first'` flag as a second parameter to unique.  Therefore:

```
[~,y,~] = unique(x, 'first');
```

If you have R2013a or higher, then you don't need to worry about this... but it's something to remember should you have something older.

Comment: ++1 since it doesn't require adding the -1 like my solution. But does MATLAB really produce that result? Octave requires me to use `[~,y,~] = unique(x, "first")`, otherwise it returns the indices of the last unique elements (`3    5    9   10`) by default.

Comment: @Praetorian yes it works on my end with MATLAB R2013a. Peculiar how in Octave you need to specify the `first` flag!

Comment: Apparently [MATLAB modified this behavior in R2013a](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) (search for *Preserve Legacy Behavior of unique*). The second return value used to be a row vector containing the last indices, but now it's a column vector containing the first indices.

Comment: @Praetorian - Ah, that explains it.  Thank you.  I will append this to my post.  I didn't see this as I have the version of MATLAB right when they changed that behaviour.